# Django server autoreaload stop working because of LOCALE_PATHS

Tags: python, django

I don't know if this is a bug in Django or a behavior that I don't understand.
When i add this in settings, dev server don't auto reload when changes are made in files.

```
 LOCALE_PATHS =('/locale/')
```

but works perfectly with this:

```
LOCALE_PATHS =('/locale/',)
```

(Note the comma)

I wasted an hour figuring out why the server was not reloading.
There's any explanation why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the trailing comma you are assigning it to a string literal instead of a tuple. Django [expects a tuple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#locale-paths) for this setting:

> LOCALE_PATHS [...] A tuple of directories where Django looks for translation files

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; **a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses)**. Ugly, but effective.